# Command + R not working on Snow Leopard reboot

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard

I am trying to install OSX (10.6) from disk, but before I do I want to format the hard drive which requires the Disk Utility from the disk.

I am pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> at start up, but the MacBook is still booting up normally. I've tried before the chime, after the chime, during the chime. Nothing.

I am using the 13" MacBook Pro Mac OS X Install DVD that came with the laptop.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is used to enter **Recovery Partition** which comes with **Lion** and **Mountain Lion**.

To start up from the installation DVD (or any bootable CD or USB, for that matter) you must reboot holding down <kbd>C</kbd> before the *chime* and hold until the Apple logo appears.

You could, too, just let it boot normally, and then run the installer (once the DVD is mounted in Finder), which will, then, start up into the DVD.

Comment: Ah! That's where I was going wrong. Thank you, works perfectly.

Comment: @JayDee My pleasure! Remember to accept the answer, so the question will be marked as, well, answered. :)